# convert android UI xml to code

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

So, I'm trying to make a dynamic UI, and i want to add a seperator to it. unfortunately, i could only find out how do one in XML. is it possible to turn this

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/seperator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark" />
```

into program code?

my best attempt was

```
ImageView seperator=new ImageView(this);
seperator.setImageDrawable(drawable.divider_horizontal_dark);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in an extra layout file and inflate it when you need it in code - I think that what you want to do and should be the easiest way.

In your Activity:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.seperator, null);
```

If you inflate a Layout:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

Comment: oh really? i can do that? wow. i've just spent three hours re-writing some XML i'd already had into code, and was nowhere near done. i think you've just saved me a LOT of time and effort... i'll set your answer as correct if this works mate. cheers.

Comment: okay, so, that works. slightly different question: if i use that layout inflater thing for a viewgroup, like, linearlayout, is there some special way i should go about editing the text in a child TextView?

Comment: Oh thank you, you saved me. I was thinking about writing 500 lines of Java codes

Answer (score 4):

There is a website can convert that for you. You can design the interface with `eclipse` then submit the generated xml to [XMLtoJAVA](http://www.xmltojava.com) online converter and it should do it for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a View, define a background and add it with a LayoutParams

```
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container); 
    View separator = new View(context);
    separator.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2);

    container.addView(separator, layoutParams);
```